# How to traverse an Abstract Syntax Tree object in python using javalang module?

Tags: java, python, static, analysis

I'm using javalang module (https://github.com/c2nes/javalang) to analyze a java code. I have no knowledge about parsing or static code analysis.

Example:

```
tree = javalang.parse.parse("-javacodelocation-")
for path,node in tree:  
        print path,node
```

This traverses through the tree and displays the path and the node name.

```
node.children()
```

gives all children of the iterator node.

I really can't figure how to traverse through this tree object properly and what all more information I can gather from the given Java code using this tree object.

Basically I just want to know more attributes,methods etc of the iterator node.

I tried using the dir(), still couldn't figure out anything useful

This is what I've implemented till now.
https://github.com/MokshTalreja/JavaCodeAnalyzer

Comment: Can you please format your code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, what do you mean by formatting?

Comment: Your given Python code is not readable, that's what ViG meant. And is there any concrete question? https://github.com/c2nes/javalang gives some basic introduction about working with Javalang

Comment: krlzlx did it for you, now the code is easy readable.

Comment: https://github.com/c2nes/javalang, I've gone through the documentation provided here, it doesn't talk much about methods and attributes of the nodes in the abstract syntax tree. Also I'm very new to this concept, so I just help in fetching more information from the tree object, where all the java code is parsed.